# Can Reporting Services 2005 report on SQL Server 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, compatibility

we would like to upgrade our SQL Server from 2005 to 2008. Unfortunately, we also have a lot of reports based on Reporting Services 2005. If possible we would like avoid upgrading them at this time.

Is it possible to run Reporting Services 2005 of SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The metadata databases for SSRS 2005 can run on SQL Server 2005 upwards. Which includes SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Note: do not open a report in a later version of BIDS: always use BIDS 2005 in VS 2005 unless you want your reports upgraded. Then you need SSRS 2008.